# How to find the maximum number of consecutive negative occurrences in GOOGLE SHEET using the specified cells?

Tags: google-sheets

I can now find the maximum number of consecutive negative occurrences of B:B.

However, my problem is that I want to find the maximum number of consecutive occurrences of negative B:B that match the C3 date by specifying the C3 date and finding B:B and A:A.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put multiple conditions in the [Boolean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-element_Boolean_algebra) expression inside the `left()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    countif(A1:A, C3), 
    max( 
      len( 
        split( 
          join( 
            "", 
            left( not( (A1:A <> C3) + (B1:B >= 0) ) ) 
          ), 
          "F" 
        ) 
      ) 
    ), 
    "(no data for date '" & to_text(C3) & "')" 
  ) 
)
```

Answer (score -1):

We will want to first sort the data, then do the operation. This is simple enough. Just change `B1:B20` to: `=FILTER(B:B, A:A = C3)`

so your final formula will look something like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(LEN(SPLIT(JOIN( "", LEFT(FILTER(B:b, A:A = C3))), "F"))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works

Comment: I think this gives the _total number of rows_ that have a negative value on the date, rather than the _max number of consecutive rows_ that meet the criteria. The results will be correct when the dates in A1:A are sorted _and_ there are no positive values in between negative values, but they will be **incorrect** when the dates are in mixed order _and also when_ there are positive values in between negative values on a date.